# Where does macOS keep list of unique webcam names that have ever connected?

Tags: macos, plist, webcam

**Use case:**

I have connected a webcam to my machine some time ago, and it was recognized as `Some Company Webcam`.
At a later time, either because I connected it to a different port, or some other inexplicable reason, now I have a `Some Company Webcam #2`.

I have not changed my webcam.  It is still the same device, connected via the same USB-C cable.

**Questions:**

1. Where does macOS keep the list of historical connections so as to know to add a `#2` at the end of the name?
2. How can I modify that list so that I would only have `Some Company Webcam` without the `#2` at the end?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue and also can't figure it out after a bit of google foo. I found dead ends elsewhere, too: https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/fnv0k8/how_to_rename_my_webcam/, etc.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this! I have a meeting rooms with 2 cameras and am getting tired of guessing which of the two named "USB Live Camera" is which. Linux has (or had 12 years ago) a solution for this using a config file that allows you to link the USB ID to a custom name. Does this not exist in MacOS? Do MacOS users only ever use a single camera?

Comment: For reference the way linux deals with this is using the udev library, which allows you to bind a specific USB ID to a custom name:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name

It seems that MacOS does not have the functionality, and alway binds the device to the OS name in the firmware, with no possibility of overriding it, which leaves us all in this annoying awkward situation...